# Custom Fields - Taller editing area

Tags: custom-field, wp-admin, users, text

Don't know if this is possible, but can the custom fields be adjusted to be taller in the admin panel? It's a bit tedious to have to stretch the textbox every time you want to edit an existing field that contains a lot of text.

Comment: You would have to create your own meta boxes to achieve this, There is a few instruction on https://www.google.com/search?q=create+custom+meta+boxes on how to do this

Answer (score 1):

### Large »Custom Field« Textareas.

Gladly those are easy to target. Wrapped up in a small plugin:

```
<?php 
! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) AND exit;
/* Plugin Name: (#65922) »kaiser« Bigger custom field textarea */

function wpse65922_big_customfield_textarea()
{
    ?>
<style type="text/css">
#the-list textarea,
#newmeta textarea {
    height: 200px;
}
</style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'wpse65922_big_customfield_textarea' );
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'wpse65922_big_customfield_textarea' );
```

This targets the existing as well as the new custom fields textareas.

[image]

### Go Fullscreen (built in) for the WYSIWG editor

Since some time, WordPress got the "Fullscreen" Mode. Just click it and the textbox expands to **the whole screen**, so you can write distraction free.

[image]
[image]

Comment: In the first snapshot, what's that icon left to WordPress logo? ::::: PS.: "Go" and "Exit fullscreen" was a nice touch, but, in the context of the question, I don't understand why you put it in the answer (?)...

Comment: @brasofilo Ad "Go/Exit") Just because we got some basic WP usage questions in the last time and I wanted to have this answered somewhere, so we can mark duplicates. Ad "icon left of logo") It's a small custom plugin, that lets me hide the WP admin bar, in case there's an error hidden below it. It's just extremely annoying to always go into the dev bar and delete the HTML node on every request and I tend to throw my errors during development at early hooks :) The icon itself is taken from the admin bar menu bottom.

Comment: Yes, indeed, sometimes the admin bar gets in the way like a kid in an adult's game... Note taken re duplicates. Danke :o[)